# Plotting a map using Shapefile and GeoPandas

Tags: python

I am using GeoPandas to plot some longitude and latitudes on a shapefile.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
oxford_map.to_crs(epsg=4326).plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey')
geo_df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Map of Oxford')
```

[image: This is the output I am getting when running. I should be getting the shapefile printed along with the plots]

Why it isn't plotting the shapefile?

Comment: `geo_df` is the dataframe created from the shapefile?

Comment: What are you trying to plot, `geo_df` or `oxford_map`?

Comment: Yes, essentially I have both my shapefile and GeoPandas dataframe formatted and now want to visualise the data by plotting the data on top of my shapefile map. By using matplotlibs subplots I though I would be able to plot both data sets on the same axis and see where things plotted

Comment: I am trying to plot oxford_map as that is the shapefile and geo_df which I believe has my location longitude and latitude

Comment: Do you want to show two shapefiles in a plot?